# Rename kong API key name

Tags: api-key, kong, kong-plugin

We want to rename kong `apikey` name from `apikey` to `api_key`, for that we tried

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/plugins/ \
    --data "name=request-transformer"  \
    --data "config.rename.headers=apikey:api_key"
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67379495/unable-to-rename-header)
We get

> {"code":5,"fields":{"consumer":null,"service":null,"route":null,"name":"request-transformer"},"message":"UNIQUE violation detected on '{consumer=null,name="request-transformer",route=null,service=null}'","name":"unique constraint violation"}

Then,request is updated as

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/plugins \
    --data "name=request-transformer"  \
    --data "name=ourservice" \
    --data "config.rename.headers=apikey:api_key"
```

result :

> {"code":2,"fields":{"name":"expected a string"},"message":"schema violation (name: expected a string)","name":"schema violation"}

We use docker based kong API GW (`kong 2.7.1`)

Comment: Do you need the user to provide the key as `apikey`, or could you configure the Key Authentication plugin using `config.key_names=api_key` to remove the need to add a transform?

Comment: @MichaelHeap We already have configured key as `apikey`, now we need to modify to `api_key`

Comment: Do you already have a request transformer plugin configured on `ourservice`?

Comment: @MichaelHeap No, we do not at the moment. Do we need to enable `transformer` plugin?

Comment: The second error is because you have two name on the post. The first error seems relative to an already global plugin configured. Can you do a GET on `/plugins` to check if you don't have an already one set up ?